# Proper use of malloc

Tags: c, linux, malloc

A chapter out of the book I have been reading has focused on memory management allocating space using malloc linux functions.

Before I read this I would make relatively small programs without allocating space.

Is it acceptable to not do anything in the way of memory allocation for applications whose memory footprint remains under 50MB? What are the repercussions of not doing so?

Comment: 1) `malloc()` is part of C, not Linux. 2) you should learn some basics of C programming and understand dynamic allocation and why you need it - program size has nothing to do with it. 3) Why is this tagged as C++? Choose a language before you go into learning it.

Comment: The OP did not mention program size. And it's not tagged as C++ any more (though I wish that we'd got the OP to clarify and learn about tagging properly; thanks though, Killian).

Comment: @Tomalak: OP says "relatively small programs" and metions "memory footprint". The tag referred to an earlier revision of the question.

Comment: @Kerrek: Pretty sure he meant in the sense of "simple"/"quick"/"non-complex", which often goes with a small amount of code. In the final paragraph (again, now edited) the memory footprint was referred to, not the size of the executable.

Comment: I realize that. I added linux because that is the main environment I am working in and thought it might affect it some. I tagged with c++ because I use it some and although it isn't the same, I was hoping an answer would also cover it as well.

Comment: @Tomalak: But all of this is missing the main point, which is *life time*. You allocate dynamically when you need memory whose life-time has to exceed the local scope. That can be necessary even in the smallest programs, depending on what you're doing.

Comment: You may be able to get away with it for a while, but I suggest you simply learn to use `malloc`. it is very very simple and over time you will learn its uses. Also, always remember to `free` what you `malloc`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Of course! Feel free to write an answer to that effect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can do without malloc for small applications, you're probably just not needing to use any heap space. Little utility programs or toy programs often don't. The things you might be doing wrong though to get by when you should be using the heap are:

1. Arrays. If you find yourself allocating large arrays 'just to make sure everything fits' then you should perhaps be using malloc. At the least, handle the error condition that everything overflows to check they really are big enough. With dynamically allocated arrays, you can make bigger ones on the fly if you find you need more space.
2. Doing too much recursion. C benefits from flattening out recursion sometimes into loops over arrays, because unlike function languages it can't optimise things properly. If you are getting your storage space by calling function lots to create it, that's pretty dangerous (the program might crash on you one day).
3. Using static pools of objects (structs, classes). Perhaps you have a ring buffer, and 15 objects that could be in it, and you have them statically allocated because you know that your buffer will never have more than 15 entries. That's kind of OK, but allowing the buffer to grow more by adding in more structs, created with malloc, might be nice.

Probably plenty more situations where programmes which don't need malloc could benefit from having it added.

Comment: Ok, are there any common conventions on use of malloc() that are good to follow? Is there an easy way to estimate how much you need to allocate? And how is the call stack size set?

Comment: @a: Why would you ever not know how much you need to allocate? If you're trying to create an array of `int` of size n, you would just say `int *arr = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));`  Also, you don't always need to do dynamic memory allocation. It's just that some times there is no other way to do it.

Comment: That makes sense. When I don't need to dynamically allocate memory, how would I determine the available stack size?

Comment: Generally, you don't need to. If you have any reason to be worried about stack size, use dynamic allocation by whacking in some pointers for your big objects and initialising them at run-time.

Comment: @a: If the amount of memory that you are allocating makes you worry about the available stack size, then you should probably do dynamic memory allocation. The stack usually has at least 50ish kilobytes and often more. If you are allocating a 50,000 character char array, then you should be doing dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answers are missing an important point. The size of memory is a relatively specific technical detail which isn't of primary interest. The crucial difference is that between *automatic* and *dynamic* storage, and the associated lifetime:

- Automatic storage ends at the end of the scope.
- Dynamic storage begins with `malloc()` and ends with `free()`, entirely at the discretion (and responsibility) of the user.

If you can and if it makes sense, everything should be automatic. This entails locality and well-defined interfaces. However, in C (not so much in C++) there comes a time when you need to talk about objects that aren't local to the scope. That's when we need dynamic allocation.

The prime example is your typical linked list. The list consists of nodes:

```
typedef struct node_tmp
{
  int data;
  struct node_tmp * next;
  struct node_tmp * prev;
} node;
```

Now to talk about such a list boils down to talking about any of its nodes and brachiate along the prev/next pointers. However, the actual nodes cannot sensibly be part of any local scope, so they are usually *dynamically allocated*:

```
node * create_list()
{
  node * p = malloc(sizeof node);  // [1]
  p->prev = p->next = 0;
  return p;
}

void free_list(node * p) // call with head node
{
  while (p->next)
  {
    node * tmp = p;
    p = p->next;
    free(tmp);                     // [2a]
  }
  free(p);                         // [2b]
}

void append_to_end(node * p, int data); // etc.
```

Here the list nodes exist outside any scope, and you have to bring them to life manually using `malloc()`, and clean them up when you're done.

You can use linked lists even in the tiniest of programs, but there's no real way around the manual allocation.

---

Edit: I thought of another example that should really convince you: You might think that you can just make the list with automatically allocated nodes:

```
node n1, n2, n3;      // an automatic linked list
n1.prev = n3.next = 0;
n1.next = &n2; n2.prev = &n1; n2.next = &n3; n3.prev = &n2;
```

But note that you cannot do this dynamically! "Dynamic" means "at runtime", but automatic variables have to be determined entirely at compile time.

Suppose you wanted a program that reads integers from the user. If it's even, you add it to the list, if it's odd you ignore it, and if it's zero you stop. You cannot possibly realize such a program with automatic allocation, because the allocation needs are only determined at runtime.

It is in such a scenario that you require `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of an application and the use of `malloc()` are two independant things. `malloc()` is used to allocate memory at runtime, when sizes are not known at compilation time.

Anyway, if you do know the maximum size of the structures that you want to play with, you can statically allocate them and build an application without using `malloc()`. Space critical software is an example of such applications.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably allocating memory statically at compile time, but not dynamically.

The possible issue when allocating everything statically are :

- you are wasting memory because you are always allocating an upper limit with a margin.
- in some case, your application will run out of memory (because your estimation was wrong for example), and and since you can not add new memory ressources at runtime it can potentially be lethal.

That being said, in some cases like real-time embedded system, it is a **requirement** to not allocate any memory dynamically at runtime. (because you have hard memory constraints, or because allocating memory can break real time)