# How Dynamic memory allocation allocates memory during run time ?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
int a[10];
```

The above code will create a array of four int variable sizes & thus the programme will be able to store only 4 integers. 
Now consider the following commands

```
int *a,*b,*c,*d;
a= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
b= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
c= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
d= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The above part of code will create four int type pointer & will allocate them memory of int size.
I learnt that dynamic memory allocation allocates memory at rum time.
I want to know that irrespective of using array or malloc(dynamic memory allocation), the user will be getting only four int sized space to store.If we rule out that it is a pointer variable with int size memory, then what will be the  use of dynamic memory allocation.In both cases , the user will get only four int spaces & to get more he will need to access the source code.So why do we use malloc or dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: I don't see the relation between `10` and "able to store only 4 integers".

Comment: You can change the amount of dynamically allocated memory _at run time_.

Comment: There's just a lot of conception to clean up here. I reommend you check out [The definitive C++ book guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: In the first case, the lifetime of the integers is equal to that of the variable `a`, which essentially extends until the end of the variable's declarative region. In the latter case, the lifetime of the integers is controlled entirely by the user (i.e. the programmer).

Comment: `a= (int*) malloc(10 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: So is the question for C or C++? Please tag accordingly, instead of both.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7284907/596781

Comment: This is tagged as C++, so why on earth are you using `malloc`? (and C style casts) At the *very least* you probably want `new`, but more likely you want `std::vector`. Interpreted as modern C++ this is absolutely horrible code.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
int a,*b;
cin >> a;
b= (int *)malloc(a*sizeof(int));
```

The user types a number `a` and gets `a` ints. The number `a` is not known to either to programmer or the compiler here.

As pointed out in the comments, this is still bad style in C++, use `std::vector` if possible. Even `new` is still better than `malloc`. But i hope the (bad) example helps to clarify the basic idea behind dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Eww for the C-style cast.

Comment: Yeah, since the question is tagged C++ one should use a vector or similar anyway....

Comment: Sprinkling `new` all over a program is discouraged in modern C++, not to talk of `malloc`

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[10];
```

The above line of code will allocate an array of 10 `int`'s of automatic storage duration, if it was within a local scope.

```
int *a,*b,*c,*d;
```

The above, however, will allocate 4 pointers to `int` also of automatic storage duration, likewise if it was within a local scope.

```
a= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
b= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
c= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
d= (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

And finally, the above will allocate `int` variable per each pointer dynamically. So, every pointer of the above will be pointing to a single `int` variable.

Do note that dynamically allocated memory can be freed and resized at runtime unlike static memory allocation. Memory of automatic storage duration are freed when run out of scope, but cannot be resized.

Comment: What's a "local function"?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that it's all just memory. But there is a difference in usage.

In the general case, you don't necessarily know ahead of time the amount of memory you will need and then time when such memory can be safely released. `malloc` and its friends are written so that they can keep track of memory used this way.

But in many special cases, you happen to know ahead of time how much memory you will need and when you will stop needing it. For example, you know you need a single integer to act as a loop counter when running a simple loop and you'll be done with it once the loop has finished executing. While `malloc` and its friends can still work for you here, local variables are simpler, less error prone and will likely be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

If you program in C, casting the result of `malloc` is unnecessary.
I suggest you to read this: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/7363182)

Then what your doing in your code with the 4 pointers is unnecessary; in fact you can just allocate an array of 4 `int` with one `malloc`:

```
int *a;
a = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
```